# How to check AMP endpoint in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I build a plugin that base on plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/ and I want to check state when the user on AMP post or page.

What is the function that allows us to check AMP endpoint in WordPress?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `is_amp_endpoint()` function to check if the currently loaded page/post is an AMP one.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest to use the `is_amp_endpoint()` function and wrap it within an existing condition, such as the following:

```
if (function_exists( 'is_amp_endpoint' ) && is_amp_endpoint()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

That way your Wordpress web site won't crash if/when the WP-AMP plugin gets disabled (or changes its behaviour / method signature).

For additional info and alternative ways to do that, check out [this blog post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/amp-tag-form-method-get-requires-including-amp-form-extension-error-fix/) that I wrote on this topic.